# GNU Octave and MATLAB compatibility issues?

Tags: matlab, octave

I've been given Matlab scripts by my teacher for a technical report, I don't know the language yet (haven't had time at all but I'll figure it out ASAP), however it doesn't matter as I only need to run the scripts I've been given and check the plots.

I have no idea why, but everyone told me that both software run almost the same identical language, and yet the scripts I've been given rarely seem to work.

This happened repeatedly with other exams, and I know it has to be something with Octave because all my friends could run the scripts just fine on MATLAB (basically I get errors and I cannot get the plots with some of the scripts).

Now, I've been using GNU/Linux distros for years and would never go back to Windows. I'm fully aware that MATLAB runs on Linux and my University even gives me a license. However, I don't see the point in using a proprietary software like MATLAB when Octave SUPPOSEDLY works the same. I'm no Richard Stallman and I do occasionally run some proprietary software like Nvidia drivers or the Steam Client, etc, but if I can avoid it I'll avoid it.

So the issue is: do I really have to run MATLAB or can I just not figure out what's going on with Octave?

I even installed and loaded the MATLAB equivalent library I'm supposed to use for usual engineering scripts. I think it was the Control System Toolbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MATLAB is not Octave and Octave is not MATLAB. Octave replicates MATLAB syntax, but adds syntax that the developers think is missing in MATLAB. This causes Octave to not be able to implement some changes introduced later to MATLAB, since these changes would break compatibility with previous version of Octave. So, Octave *tries* to emulate MATLAB, but cannot because they shot themselves in the foot in the past trying to improve on it. Also, MATLAB has very solid implementations of all sorts of algorithms that are not available in Octave, or are not as good.

Comment: Octave _generally_ gives the same result as Matlab, but they differ in more things than many people think. Something as simple as `[~, b] = unique([10 20 10 30 20])` gives `b = [1;2;4]`  in recent versions of Matlab but `b = [3 5 4]` in Octave. This is often caused by some change introduced in Matlab that has not been applied (yet?) to Octave. Other times, one has more functionality than the other: `diff('abc')` works in Matlab, but in Octave you need `diff(double('abc'))`.  And sometimes they just work differently: in Matlab, `char(41.7)` gives `')'` (floor), in Octave it gives `'*'` (round)

Comment: @CrisLuengo tbh, I don't think prior improvements to the language matter too much in terms of sabotaging matlab compatibility. As Luis pointed out, all it takes is for matlab to do something like change their own internal defaults, like in the `unique` example above. This effectively breaks _matlab's_ backwards compatibility. Effectively Octave always has a decision to make whether to keep backwards compatibility and break _matlab_ compatibility, or keep matlab compatibility and break _backwards_ one. In this particular example, they opted for the former, but added a 'first'/'last' option.

Comment: @GiorgioDT as per the above discussion, you shouldn't think of matlab/octave as 100% compatible between _scripts_, but as 'largely compatible languages'. I.e. it's possible to write code carefully such that it's possible to run it in either environment. But, code that was written in one without explicitly ensuring compatibility with the other, is likely to run into problems, especially when toolkits/packages are involved. A way to think about it is like how C/C++ have a common subset. Or Python 2 vs 3. Even Matlab v6 vs v9: you can write code that will run on both, but they're different beasts

Comment: @Tasos: I was thinking particularly about Octave creating a character vector with the double-quote, which effectively makes it impossible for them to ever implement string arrays. The same story applies to how to define a function within an M-file. The order of sorting in `unique` is a rather minor issue compared to those.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I gathered, and obviously a small part of this is me playing "devil's advocate" ... but at the same time I don't consider these to be insurmountable issues either to be honest. If the octave team _did_ want to implement these features purely for matlab compatibility, it would be relatively trivial to make this behaviour part of the `octave --traditional` switch (aka `octave --braindead`, apparently, ahahah). E.g. this is the approach suggested by the [EEGLAB suite](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Running_EEGLAB_on_Octave).